# css not called in wkhtmltopdf 64 bit -v 0.9.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using `wkhtmltopdf v0.9.6`, 32-bit static binary with `pdfkit`. It works as expected (without header, footer, etc). The server has a 64-bit OS, so the PDF file appears with a header and footer.

I want to **remove** the header and footer. I have tried with using CSS, but it doesn't seem to work. I am using `Rails 3.2.11` and `ruby 1.8.7` without the asset pipeline.

Kindly give me a suggestion how I can remove the unwanted header and footer.

Comment: What do your HTML and CSS look like?